# Ruby GTK3, scale an image

Tags: ruby, image, gtk, gtk3

Been looking through the ruby-gtk3 api docs and I have been unable to find a way to resize an image. When inspecting the methods of an instantiated `Gtk::Image` it lists `scale_factor` as a method with no way to change it. Is there something I'm missing here? Is there a way to get the width and height of my image via Gtk::Image's methods?

Comment: I have still pain form GTK2 ... lol

Comment: If you know how to do it in GTK2 it should be compatible with GTK3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/2.22/

in particular, you want to take a look at:

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/2.22/gdk-pixbuf-scaling.html

Later, you have to find out how this is done in the ruby binding

:)

Comment: Ahh, I see PixBuf is what I needed! Ty!